# Excel VBA ARRAY Loop to Database

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, pivot

I have a huge challenge which is: Search a massive database, a list of products. This database is divided into 3 dif. sheets. The result should be stored on a 4th sheet and organized by date in columns and summarized by quantity. Each database sheet has the same format (Product / Date / Quantity).
I was told that a vba array would work perfectly.
Any help will be very appreciated.
Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le3HK.jpg)

Comment: Merge those 3 sheets into the 4th sheet and use Pivot Table afterwards. You do not need to use arrays.

Comment: Thanks Wils, for your advice but these worksheets are huge (+/- 20K lines with multiples columns) and they are not exactly in the same format. I Pivot table was considered but didn't work well. Unfortunately we need to loop into those databases and extract what is asked. Thanks

Comment: What excel version do you have? you could accomplish this with PowerQuery

Comment: Hi Ricardo. Thanks for your feedback. I read about Power Query and it looks powerful, but I think it will be more challenging to move the whole process to it. This template is already in place and some features is already running in vba. So, my mission is to speed it up the search process and build the summary. I'm not familiar with arrays, but I just need a starting point to develop the code from there. If someone has a standard code on how to look for strings/dates in rows and columns to capture the findings, it would help a lot. Thanks anyway for the advice. 
btw, Excel Microsoft 365 Pro.

Comment: Should the products be sorted (ascending) or just stay as they appear?

Comment: Yes sure. There is no problem to sort it. Actually, the summary sheet shows the products already sorted. I added a picture ah the beginning of this post just to give an idea about the format of data and the goal. Thanks.

Comment: Hello VBasic2008, sorry my delay. I was delighted looking at this MASTERPIECE you just created. it's amazing how you make everything look so simple. I'm still validating the results by it seems perfect.. Please allow me to ask you this: Let's assume that the dates in row 2 ("Summary" - Cells D2") are predefined in weeks (Monday days) and cover the next 26 weeks (from column "E" to column "AC" + another column ("D")) with due date to cover all dates in the past. How should I rearrange this code to get the same result as this? Thank you very much for all your attention and support!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Pivot (Multiple Worksheets)

[image]

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub PivotMulti()
    
    ' Data
    Const srcList As String = "Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3"
    Const srcFirst As String = "A2"
    ' Destination
    Const dstName As String = "SUMMARY"
    Const dstFirst As String = "B2"
    Const TitlesList As String = "Source Data,Product"
    ' Other
    Const Delimiter As String = "###"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define Data Ranges and write their values to arrays of Data Array.
    Dim srcNames() As String: srcNames = Split(srcList, ",")
    Dim sUpper As Long: sUpper = UBound(srcNames)
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(0 To sUpper)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dCount As Long
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To sUpper
        With wb.Worksheets(srcNames(n)).Range(srcFirst)
            Set rng = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).Find( _
                What:="*", _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            Data(n) = .Resize(rng.Row - .Row + 1, 3).Value
            dCount = dCount + UBound(Data(n))
        End With
    Next n
    
    ' Define data structures.
    Dim dictS As Object: Set dictS = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dictS.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    Dim dictD As Object: Set dictD = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim arlS As Object: Set arlS = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Dim arlD As Object: Set arlD = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim CurrString As String
    Dim CurrDate As Date
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    
    ' Write values from Data Array to dictionaries and array lists
    ' (dictianaries for 'unique' and 'sum', array lists for 'sort').
    For n = 0 To sUpper
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data(n), 1)
            CurrDate = Data(n)(i, 2)
            If Not dictD.Exists(CurrDate) Then
                arlD.Add CurrDate
                dictD(CurrDate) = Empty
            End If
            CurrString = Data(n)(i, 1) & Delimiter & srcNames(n) & Delimiter _
                & Format(CurrDate, "yyyymmdd") & Delimiter & CurrDate
            dictS(CurrString) = dictS(CurrString) + Data(n)(i, 3)
        Next i
    Next n
    Set dictD = Nothing
    Erase Data
    Erase srcNames
    arlD.Sort
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    For Each Key In dictS.Keys
        arlS.Add Key & Delimiter & dictS(Key)
    Next Key
    Set dictS = Nothing
    arlS.Sort
    
    ' Define Result Array.
    Dim rrCount As Long: rrCount = 1 + arlS.Count
    Dim rcCount As Long: rcCount = 2 + arlD.Count
    Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To rrCount, 1 To rcCount)
    
    ' Write headers.
    Dim Titles() As String: Titles = Split(TitlesList, ",")
    Result(1, 1) = Titles(0)
    Result(1, 2) = Titles(1)
    Erase Titles
    j = 2
    For Each Key In arlD
        j = j + 1
        Result(1, j) = Key
    Next Key
    
    ' Write 'body'.
    Dim Current() As String
    Dim Previous(0 To 1) As String
    i = 1
    For Each Key In arlS
        i = i + 1
        Current = Split(Key, Delimiter)
        If Current(0) <> Previous(0) Or Current(1) <> Previous(1) Then
            For j = 1 To 2
                Result(i, j) = Current(2 - j)
            Next j
        Else
            i = i - 1
        End If
        CurrDate = CDate(Current(3))
        Result(i, 3 + arlD.IndexOf(CurrDate, 0)) = CDbl(Current(4))
        Previous(0) = Current(0)
        Previous(1) = Current(1)
    Next Key
    Set arlD = Nothing
    Set arlS = Nothing
    
    ' Write values from Result Array to Destination Range.
    With wb.Worksheets(dstName).Range(dstFirst).Resize(, rcCount)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ' Worksheet
        .Worksheet.Cells.Clear
        ' Range
        With .Resize(i)
            .Value = Result ' Write.
            With .Borders
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
        End With
        ' Headers
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Interior.Color = vbYellow
        ' Body
        With .Resize(i - 1).Offset(1)
            '.Font.Color = vbRed
        End With
        ' Columns
        .Columns.AutoFit
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Data transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello VBasic2008, sorry my delay. I was delighted looking at this MASTERPIECE you just created. it's amazing how you make everything look so simple. I'm still validating the results by it seems perfect..
Please allow me to ask you this:
Let's assume that the dates in row 2 ("Summary" - Cells D2") are predefined in weeks (Monday days) and cover the next 26 weeks (from column "E" to column "AC" + another column ("D")) with due date to cover all dates in the past. How should I rearrange this code to get the same result as this?
Thank you very much for all your attention and support!!!

Comment: I think this would require a rather big fix. You should consider posting another question and this time include `1.` some code (maybe this, but clearly stating that it creates `SUMMARY` from scratch, but you require the results when its 1st row is already written), `2.` sample data as text (so it can be copy/pasted; nobody likes to type the data) and `3.` an image(s) **accurately** (note the differences between our images) showing before and after.

Comment: Also rephrase this *"+ another column ("D")) with due date to cover all dates in the past"* clarifying what it means (is it an empty column?) and if the dates in the source data will be only Mondays or any date (another challenge; fitting the dates into weeks). Then on this page you can post a link in your post or the comments so I can find it.

Comment: Thank You VBAsic2008. I just created a new post called "Excel VBA Multiple Matches Using Arrays". I have some sample data but didn't find a way to attach it. I added a picture with a guide with a template format that I'm looking for. Really appreciated your support.

Comment: @br1912 - allow me a hint: if this approach is helpful showing the way to go & comes close to your requirements, it'd be good use to accept by ticking the green checkmark.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I haven't figured out how to close my post and thanks for the support.